# java process to notify the shell spring load completion

Tags: spring, bash, jmx

I use spring in a stand alone web application, which means there's no servlet container but rather it runs in a JVM machine:

```
public class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {       
        AbstractApplicationContext  context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
        context.registerShutdownHook();
    }   
}
```

Once built, i run it from a bash shell like this, for the sake of simplicity let's call it process 'main' and figure that it's run in a shell script:

```
me@local$ java A
```

This command starts a JVM and runs the main function above in the 'main' process, this main function never returns   and thus:

1. i find it hard to figure out how the process would notify the shell
   from any event in spring. I'm using jmx to monitorize the process
   and i need the shell to be aware of the spring load completion for
   it's used to start other processes that depends upon this process
   'main' and the bash script.
2. The script where the process is started
       cannot continue.

For point 2, the obvious answer:

```
me@local$ java A &
```

Doesn't build anything, since eventhough the script can continue, i cannot notify the shell when spring finished to load.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why is it not enough just to output something on console after your application is ready? Also, you could connect by jmx right after a java process has been launched, then you could monitor jmx beans.

Comment: I think that's the only solution if i want to go on with the script: put the process in background and the next process in the script would read in the console until my process logs it's ready. Anyway i think i should redo all this so that i'd use a java process to orchestrate all the initialization instead of a shell script.

Comment: Yes, you are right. BTW, I'm currently investigating the newest JBossAS 7, it has a server domain mode, and looks like it allows to orchestrate bunch of java applications, even among several computers. But not sure how good is it.